# Ruby gem or regex to extract IPs from 0-255?

Tags: regex, ruby

I've seen several regex examples on extracting IP addresses, but I haven't been able to find one that matches 0-255 and work perfectly just yet. Here's what I've been using for quite some time:

```
ips = data.scan(/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/m).uniq
```

However, this captures things way outside of 0-255. I tried adding this as well:

```
ips = data.scan(/((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))/m).uniq
```

but then it looks like this started causing some issues as well.

Comment: What are the issues with the second one?

Comment: For whatever reason, it came back as an empty array. The line that it was parsing had an IP address of 172.16.210.1

Comment: Use `/\b(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\b/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QKTxzJ/1).

Comment: This is a pretty common regular expression to see if you work with IPv4 values.